# How to reduce file size of large data set

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and working on a matrix of dimension 20000x20000. Now I need to store elements of matrix in a file in form of set {i,j,value}, with one set per line. I tried "file.write" function to store all elements into a text file by converting each set to a string but by doing this file size is becoming around 6GB. 
I want to know is there any way to reduce file size or size of the set so that overall size can be reduced?

Comment: What are the types of `i`, `j`, and `value`? Integers, strings, ...?

Comment: "i" and "j" are the index values of the matrix thus are integers and "value" is of double type.

Comment: If one special value is expected to be very frequent in the matrix, you can omit it from the file. For example, if many cells are 0., this will give you a sparse matrix representation. And if the matrix is not sparse, you can omit the `i` and `j` index from each line and deduce them from the line number. Posted as a comment because I don't know whether this really addresses your problem...

Answer (score 0):

You can try compressing the file. Example of `gzip` compression from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#examples-of-usage)

```
import gzip
content = b"Lots of content here"
with gzip.open('/home/joe/file.txt.gz', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(content)
```

Comment: Isn't there any other way except compression like using different data structure or different file type?